# extract second last Substring in bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, substring

I am trying to get the substring which lies between the last & second last fullstop (.) in a filename using the batch file, filename can have any number of fullstops. The file name will look like as follows, in this particular example output should be '8'.

filename: a_b_c_d_e.1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9

I tried the below part, but it always outputs the string after the first fullstop i.e 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9 instead of '8'.

**set "string=a_b_c_d_e.1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9"**

**@echo %string:*.=%**

**pause**

Any working suggestions can be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the file modifier syntax.

Replace all dots with backslashes and then take the parent directory by appending `\..`

```
@echo off
set "string=a_b_c_d_e.1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9"

for /F "delims=" %%X in ("%string:.=\%\..") do echo %%~nX
```

Comment: Thanks @jeb. Solved a problem for me.

Comment: can it be used if the filenames are stored in another text file like filename.txt, instead of a variable ?

Comment: @AmitSingla Then you should read it from that file into a variable

Comment: got it, will try that also.

Comment: tried the below code to read the filenames & process it further, but batch file closed abruptly. It seems nested for loop is causing the problem . Your thoughts please. 
                      " `@echo off set "File2Read=filelist.txt" for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "%File2Read%"') do ( echo %%a ) for /F "delims=" %%X in ("%a:.=\%\..") do echo %%~nX`"

Comment: You should ask a new question. Hint,you can't use variable search/replace syntax on a for-meta-variable